# How can I do "SELECT" query with "WHERE" condition on column that does not exist in the table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

To understand the question, I'll show an example: my columns in the `Students` table are:

```
stuID, cityID, Name, updateDate
```

and my SELECT is:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cityID ORDER BY updateDate DESC) AS rownumber 
    stuID,
    cityID,
    Name
FROM
    Students 
WHERE 
    rownumber = 1
```

No matter - why I wish to make such a query, this is only example, but how can I put in the "WHERE" condition on rownumber????

Answer (score 8):

The `WHERE` Clause will be evaluated immediately after `FROM` Clause,so SQL has no idea when you refer to somevalue you refered in select

Use CTE/SubQuery if you want to apply predicate to RowNumber :

```
 ;With cte
    as
    (
    SELECT
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cityID ORDER BY updateDate DESC) AS rownumber 
          stuID,
          cityID,
          Name
    FROM Students 

    )
    select * from cte where rownumber=1
```

Below are the logical querying phases which dictates how  the clauses defined in one Phase are made available to the clauses in next phases..

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3.OUTER
4.WHERE
5.GROUP BY
6.CUBE | ROLLUP
7.HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. TOP
11. ORDER BY
```

As you can see ,`RowNumber` you have defined  in `select` clause which will be available only to next phases after select

[Below is the Logical query processing flow chart for each clause :Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Any aliases and calculated fields are available if you put your query into subquery or CTE:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cityID ORDER BY updateDate DESC) AS rownumber 
          stuID,
          cityID,
          Name
    FROM Students
) s
WHERE rownumber = 1
```